# Not All Entries showing in feed page but do show in Page Source XML

Tags: entries, rss, xml

Creating an RSS feed in craft and I have it to loop through all the entries via:

```
    {% set sermons = craft.entries.section('sermonEntry').limit(null).find() %}
    {% for sermon in sermons %}
```

On my feed url (example.com/feed) I can only see 17 of my entries. However when I view the page source. I see all of my entries in XML format (roughly 31 entries)

Anyone have an idea why this may be? Or if it will affect my podcasts that go to itunes?

I am not sure if there is a limitation on atom or rss with craft but I have seen 100's of entries on a rss feed page so maybe I am overlooking something?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are any of the entries disabled/turned off?  Do any of the entries have expiration dates or are set to post in the future?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I have all the entries paginated and displaying fine on example.com/sermons.

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally had loop inside of the description tag which strangely caused only 17 entries to post to the RSS feed. Below is an example of what was causing the issue:

```
<description><![CDATA[
  {% set speaker = craft.categories.group('speaker').relatedTo(entry).find() %}
  {% for name in speaker %}
  A Sermon from {{ entry.sermondate | date("l, F j, Y") }}: {{ entry.title }} by {{ name.title }}]]></description>
        <category>Podcasts</category>
        <category>Christianity</category>
        <author>{{ name.title }}</author>
        <itunes:explicit>No</itunes:explicit>
        <itunes:author>{{ name.title }}</itunes:author>{% endfor %}
```

After I set it outside the Description tag if gave me all my entries on the RSS feed. Here is my final feed code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <rss xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" version="2.0">
    <channel>
    <title>Sermons at Example Church</title>
    <atom:link href="{{ url() }}" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <link>http://www.examplechurch.org/sermons/</link>
    <description>Weekly morning sermons from Example Church in Sab Diego, CA. For all of our sermon archives, please visit http://www.example.org/sermons.</description>
    <lastBuildDate>Sun, 17 Sep 2017 00:00:00 -0600</lastBuildDate>
    <language>en-us</language>
    <sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod>
    <sy:updateFrequency>1</sy:updateFrequency>
    <itunes:author>Example Church</itunes:author>
    <itunes:summary>Weekly morning sermons from Example Church in Sab Diego, CA. For all of our sermon archives, please visit http://www.example.org/sermons.</itunes:summary>
    <itunes:owner>
      <itunes:name>Example Church - San Diego, California</itunes:name>
      <itunes:email>web@examplechurch.org</itunes:email>
    </itunes:owner>
    <itunes:explicit>No</itunes:explicit>
    <itunes:category text="Religion &amp; Spirituality">
    <itunes:category text="Christianity"></itunes:category>
    </itunes:category>
    <itunes:category text="Health"></itunes:category>
    <itunes:category text="Society &amp; Culture"></itunes:category>
     {% if podcastImage.podcastimage|length %}
    <itunes:image href="{{ podcastImage.podcastimage.first.getUrl() }}"></itunes:image>
     {% endif %}
    {% set entries = craft.entries.section('sermonEntry').limit(null).find() %}
     {% for entry in entries %}
    <item>
      <title>{{ entry.title }}</title>
      <link>{{ entry.url }}</link>
      <pubDate>{{ entry.postDate.rss }}</pubDate>
       {% set audio = entry.audio.first() %}
       {% if audio %}
      <enclosure url="{{ audio.url }}" type="audio/mp3"></enclosure>
       {% endif %}
      <guid>{{ entry.url }}</guid>
       {% set speaker = craft.categories.group('speaker').relatedTo(entry).find() %}
      {% for name in speaker %}
      <description><![CDATA[A Sermon from {{ entry.sermondate | date("l, F j, Y") }}: {{ entry.title }} by {{ name.title }}]]></description>
      <category>Podcasts</category>
      <category>Christianity</category>
      <author>{{ name.title }}</author>
      <itunes:explicit>No</itunes:explicit>
      <itunes:author>{{ name.title }}</itunes:author>{% endfor %}
      <itunes:keywords>Example Church,Sermons,Christianity,Jesus Christ,Bible Teaching,Discipleship,Service</itunes:keywords>
     </item>
     {% endfor %}
   </channel>
   </rss>
```